# Why are some system tables determined to be a "fake table" using the "TableIsFake" ObjectProperty?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, metadata

I was looking over the `ObjectProperty` list today and came across the property `TableIsFake`.  The name amused me, so I looked at what it checks:

> The table is not real. It is materialized internally on demand by SQL Server.

What exactly does this mean?  For example, when I run the following query:

```
SELECT [name], xtype
FROM dbo.sysobjects
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id([name]), N'TableIsFake') = 1 
ORDER BY [name]
```

I get the following results:

```
name           xtype
-------------- -----
sysfiles       S 
sysforeignkeys S 
sysindexkeys   S 
sysmembers     S 
sysprotects    S
```

But if I query the database for system tables:

```
SELECT [name], xtype
FROM dbo.sysobjects
WHERE xtype = 'S'
ORDER BY [name]
```

I get the following system tables:

```
name                xtype
------------------- -----
syscolumns          S 
syscomments         S 
sysdepends          S 
sysfilegroups       S 
sysfiles            S 
sysfiles1           S 
sysforeignkeys      S 
sysfulltextcatalogs S 
sysfulltextnotify   S 
sysindexes          S 
sysindexkeys        S 
sysmembers          S 
sysobjects          S 
syspermissions      S 
sysproperties       S 
sysprotects         S 
sysreferences       S 
systypes            S 
sysusers            S
```

What makes the `sysfiles`, `sysforeignkeys`, `sysindexkeys`, `sysmembers`, `sysprotects` system tables "fake"?  Or put another way, what does it mean that they are "materialized internally on demand by SQL Server"?  Does that mean they are only created when a process needs it, or if I call something like `SELECT * FROM sysfiles`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fake table is a special "in memory" structure with no on-disk persistence. SQL Server creates it on demand.

The best example is sysprocesses.

IMHO: the key is "on disk persistence":

- sysusers or sysxlogins (for example) are real tables in each db/master respectively and survive backups/restores
- sysprocesses or sysfiles will not survive a backup/restore because there is nothing to write or read to disk

Comment: Makes sense but any idea why `USE master; SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('sysprocesses'), N'TableIsFake')` returns `NULL` rather than `1`?

Answer (score 1):

The sysfiles table is really a view and is created like that for backwards compatibility
See [Mapping System Tables to System Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187997.aspx) to see what you should be using

So instead of sysfiles, you should use sys.database_files

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm testing this in SQL Server 2000. Edited my question tags.